# Python Newby Help. Illegal instruction (core dumped) in for loop

Tags: python, coredump

Just tranfered my VBox Ubuntu to a different computer, along with all my data.

I discovered this block of code (bottom line gives error) now gives me a problem when running on the new system.

```
total_bins3 = int(54000)
    bins3 = np.linspace(time.min(),time.max(), total_bins3)
    delta3 = bins3[1]-bins3[0]
    idx3  = np.digitize(time,bins3)
    running_median3 = [np.median(Y[idx3==k]) for k in range(total_bins3)]#line gives error

Illegal Instruction (core dumped)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

J

Comment: That doesn't look like an ordinary Python exception. Those usually look like a traceback followed by "<Something>Error: <explanation>". Possibly this error came from the compiled-from-C part of numpy. Are you sure you installed it correctly?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I installed numpy via pip. Is there another way to install it that will not give me this error? Thanks for your help